# Links not working after Drupal site migration

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I moved a drupal installation from one server to localhost. Steps I followed:

1. Copied whole directory structure from old server.
2. Exported database from old server.
3. added files to newdomain/drupal
4. Imported database
5. edited settings.php with new database information.

As of right now the home page is working. But none of the links to any of the nodes or any of the admin paths I know seem to exist. I get the localhost home page.
Any ideas ?

Comment: When you check the content tab, do you see a list of all the nodes? And if they are listed there, can you visit them?

Comment: i cant visit ! any button or link is moving to localhost home page like : http://localhost/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have `.htaccess` file in the site folder?
please try with default .htaccees file for your Drupal version